# How to crawl redirected URLs?

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I'm trying to crawl a list of websites that I don't know their exact addresses. some of them are *https* and other ones are *http* or may have *www* in their URL or may have not and I just have their host addresses. here is an example:

```
spouts:
  - id: "spout"
    className: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.spout.MemorySpout"
    parallelism: 1
    constructorArgs:
      - ["https://digikala.com/"]
```

And this is the result after crawling:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "url":"https://digikala.com/",
        "host":"digikala.com",
        "status":"REDIRECTION",
        "metadata._redirTo":["https://www.digikala.com/"],
        "nextFetchDate":"2019-09-17T06:34:38Z"}]
  }}
```

I want to if a website is redirected, the crawler DISCOVER the redirected URL and all of its sublinks.
How can I achieve this?
This is my *urlfilters.json*:

```
{
    "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.URLFilters": [
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.basic.BasicURLFilter",
            "name": "BasicURLFilter",
            "params": {
                "maxPathRepetition": 8,
                "maxLength": 8192
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.depth.MaxDepthFilter",
            "name": "MaxDepthFilter",
            "params": {
                "maxDepth": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.basic.BasicURLNormalizer",
            "name": "BasicURLNormalizer",
            "params": {
                "removeAnchorPart": true,
                "unmangleQueryString": true,
                "checkValidURI": true,
                "removeHashes": false
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.host.HostURLFilter",
            "name": "HostURLFilter",
            "params": {
                "ignoreOutsideHost": true,
                "ignoreOutsideDomain": false
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.regex.RegexURLNormalizer",
            "name": "RegexURLNormalizer",
            "params": {
                "regexNormalizerFile": "default-regex-normalizers.xml"
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.regex.RegexURLFilter",
            "name": "RegexURLFilter",
            "params": {
                "regexFilterFile": "default-regex-filters.txt"
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.basic.SelfURLFilter",
            "name": "SelfURLFilter"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is my *crawler-conf.yaml*:

```
config: 
  fetcher.server.delay: 1.0
  fetcher.server.min.delay: 0.0
  fetcher.queue.mode: "byHost"
  fetcher.threads.per.queue: 1
  fetcher.threads.number: 10
  fetcher.max.urls.in.queues: -1
  fetcher.max.queue.size: -1
  fetcher.max.crawl.delay: 30

  fetcher.max.crawl.delay.force: false

  fetcher.server.delay.force: false

  fetcher.metrics.time.bucket.secs: 10


  fetcher.max.throttle.sleep: -1

  partition.url.mode: "byHost"


  metadata.persist:
   - _redirTo
   - error.cause
   - error.source
   - isSitemap
   - isFeed

  metadata.track.path: true
  metadata.track.depth: true

  http.agent.name: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36"
  http.agent.version: "537.36"
  http.agent.description: "Free open-source web browser developed by Google. Chromium is the name of the open source project behind Google Chrome, released under the BSD license."
  http.agent.url: "http://www.google.com/chrome"
  http.agent.email: "someone@someorganization.com"

  http.accept.language: "en-us,en-gb,en;q=0.7,*;q=0.3"
  http.accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
  http.content.limit: -1
  http.store.headers: false
  http.timeout: 10000


  http.content.partial.as.trimmed: false


  http.robots.403.allow: true

  robots.noFollow.strict: false
  http.skip.robots: true
  robots.cache.spec: "maximumSize=10000,expireAfterWrite=6h"
  robots.error.cache.spec: "maximumSize=10000,expireAfterWrite=1h"

  protocols: "http,https,file"
  http.protocol.implementation: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.protocol.httpclient.HttpProtocol"
  https.protocol.implementation: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.protocol.httpclient.HttpProtocol"
  file.protocol.implementation: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.protocol.file.FileProtocol"

  selenium.implicitlyWait: 0
  selenium.pageLoadTimeout: -1
  selenium.setScriptTimeout: 0
  selenium.instances.num: 1
  selenium.capabilities:
    takesScreenshot: false
    loadImages: false
    javascriptEnabled: true

  selenium.delegated.protocol: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.protocol.httpclient.HttpProtocol"

  # no url or parsefilters by default
  parsefilters.config.file: "parsefilters.json"
  urlfilters.config.file: "urlfilters.json"
  # JSoupParserBolt
  jsoup.treat.non.html.as.error: true
  parser.emitOutlinks: false
  parser.emitOutlinks.max.per.page: -1
  track.anchors: true
  detect.mimetype: true
  detect.charset.maxlength: 10000

  # filters URLs in sitemaps based on their modified Date (if any)
  sitemap.filter.hours.since.modified: -1

  # staggered scheduling of sitemaps
  sitemap.schedule.delay: -1


  sitemap.discovery: true

  scheduler.class: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.persistence.DefaultScheduler"


  fetchInterval.default: 1440
  fetchInterval.fetch.error: 120

  # never revisit a page with an error (or set a value in minutes)
  fetchInterval.error: -1


  max.fetch.errors: 3

  status.updater.use.cache: true
  status.updater.cache.spec: "maximumSize=10000,expireAfterAccess=1h"

  status.updater.unit.round.date: "SECOND"

  indexer.url.fieldname: "url"
  indexer.text.fieldname: "content"
  indexer.text.maxlength: -1
  indexer.canonical.name: "canonical"
  indexer.md.mapping:
  - parse.title=title
  - parse.keywords=keywords
  - parse.description=description
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the links within the same top-level domain by simply setting

```
            "ignoreOutsideHost": false,
            "ignoreOutsideDomain": true
```

in the config of the HostURLFilter. This would deal with variations such as www.; note that the protocol itself does not play any role.

If you wanted to follow redirections across different TLDs, you'd have to write your own URL filter as HostURLFilter does not distinguish between redirections and outlinks.

Comment: Right. as I mentioned in my question, this the exact config that I'm using, but still does not crawl the redirected URL and just shows `"status":"REDIRECTION"`

Comment: apologies, had cut and paste bt forgotten to modify the values. See updated answer above

Comment: the source URL will still show REDIRECTION, and that's not going to change. You'll have the target added as DISCOVERED though and it will be fetched later on

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have another strange problem, there is a website that I'm trying to crawl, the crawler DISCOVER and FETCH the URLs but there is nothing in *docs*. this the website `https://cactussara.ir`! where is the problem?!

Comment: please open another question for it - will make it easier for others to contribute

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57955781/stormcrawler-discover-and-fetch-a-website-but-nothing-gets-saved-in-docs