# StormCrawler DISCOVER and FETCH a website but nothing gets saved in docs

Tags: stormcrawler

There is a website that I'm trying to crawl, the crawler DISCOVER and FETCH the URLs but there is nothing in docs. this is 
the website `https://cactussara.ir`. where is the problem?!
And this is the `robots.txt` of this website:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

And this is my *urlfilters.json*:

```
{
    "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.URLFilters": [
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.basic.BasicURLFilter",
            "name": "BasicURLFilter",
            "params": {
                "maxPathRepetition": 8,
                "maxLength": 8192
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.depth.MaxDepthFilter",
            "name": "MaxDepthFilter",
            "params": {
                "maxDepth": -1
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.basic.BasicURLNormalizer",
            "name": "BasicURLNormalizer",
            "params": {
                "removeAnchorPart": true,
                "unmangleQueryString": true,
                "checkValidURI": true,
                "removeHashes": false
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.host.HostURLFilter",
            "name": "HostURLFilter",
            "params": {
                "ignoreOutsideHost": true,
                "ignoreOutsideDomain": false
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.regex.RegexURLNormalizer",
            "name": "RegexURLNormalizer",
            "params": {
                "regexNormalizerFile": "default-regex-normalizers.xml"
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.regex.RegexURLFilter",
            "name": "RegexURLFilter",
            "params": {
                "regexFilterFile": "default-regex-filters.txt"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is *crawler-conf.yaml*:

```
# Default configuration for StormCrawler
# This is used to make the default values explicit and list the most common configurations.
# Do not modify this file but instead provide a custom one with the parameter -conf
# when launching your extension of ConfigurableTopology.  

config: 
  fetcher.server.delay: 1.0
  # min. delay for multi-threaded queues
  fetcher.server.min.delay: 0.0
  fetcher.queue.mode: "byHost"
  fetcher.threads.per.queue: 1
  fetcher.threads.number: 10
  fetcher.max.urls.in.queues: -1
  fetcher.max.queue.size: -1
  # max. crawl-delay accepted in robots.txt (in seconds)
  fetcher.max.crawl.delay: 30
  # behavior of fetcher when the crawl-delay in the robots.txt
  # is larger than fetcher.max.crawl.delay:
  #  (if false)
  #    skip URLs from this queue to avoid that any overlong
  #    crawl-delay throttles the crawler
  #  (if true)
  #    set the delay to fetcher.max.crawl.delay,
  #    making fetcher more aggressive than requested
  fetcher.max.crawl.delay.force: false
  # behavior of fetcher when the crawl-delay in the robots.txt
  # is smaller (ev. less than one second) than the default delay:
  #  (if true)
  #    use the larger default delay (fetcher.server.delay)
  #    and ignore the shorter crawl-delay in the robots.txt
  #  (if false)
  #    use the delay specified in the robots.txt
  fetcher.server.delay.force: false

  # time bucket to use for the metrics sent by the Fetcher
  fetcher.metrics.time.bucket.secs: 10

  # SimpleFetcherBolt: if the delay required by the politeness
  # is above this value, the tuple is sent back to the Storm queue 
  # for the bolt on the _throttle_ stream.
  fetcher.max.throttle.sleep: -1

  # alternative values are "byIP" and "byDomain"
  partition.url.mode: "byHost"

  # metadata to transfer to the outlinks
  # used by Fetcher for redirections, sitemapparser, etc...
  # these are also persisted for the parent document (see below)
  # metadata.transfer:
  # - customMetadataName

  # lists the metadata to persist to storage
  # these are not transfered to the outlinks
  metadata.persist:
   - _redirTo
   - error.cause
   - error.source
   - isSitemap
   - isFeed

  metadata.track.path: true
  metadata.track.depth: true

  http.agent.name: "Anonymous Coward"
  http.agent.version: "1.0"
  http.agent.description: "built with StormCrawler ${version}"
  http.agent.url: "http://someorganization.com/"
  http.agent.email: "someone@someorganization.com"

  http.accept.language: "fa-IR,fa_IR,en-us,en-gb,en;q=0.7,*;q=0.3"
  http.accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
  http.content.limit: -1
  http.store.headers: false
  http.timeout: 10000
  http.skip.robots: true

  # store partial fetches as trimmed content (some content has been fetched,
  # but reading more data from socket failed, eg. because of a network timeout)
  http.content.partial.as.trimmed: false

  # for crawling through a proxy:
  # http.proxy.host:
  # http.proxy.port:
  # okhttp only, defaults to "HTTP"
  # http.proxy.type: "SOCKS"
  # for crawling through a proxy with Basic authentication:
  # http.proxy.user:
  # http.proxy.pass:

  http.robots.403.allow: true

  # should the URLs be removed when a page is marked as noFollow
  robots.noFollow.strict: false

  # Guava caches used for the robots.txt directives 
  robots.cache.spec: "maximumSize=10000,expireAfterWrite=6h"
  robots.error.cache.spec: "maximumSize=10000,expireAfterWrite=1h"

  protocols: "http,https,file"
  http.protocol.implementation: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.protocol.httpclient.HttpProtocol"
  https.protocol.implementation: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.protocol.httpclient.HttpProtocol"
  file.protocol.implementation: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.protocol.file.FileProtocol"

  # navigationfilters.config.file: "navigationfilters.json"
  # selenium.addresses: "http://localhost:9515"
  selenium.implicitlyWait: 0
  selenium.pageLoadTimeout: -1
  selenium.setScriptTimeout: 0
  selenium.instances.num: 1
  selenium.capabilities:
    takesScreenshot: false
    loadImages: false
    javascriptEnabled: true
    # illustrates the use of the variable for user agent
    # phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent: "$userAgent"
    # ChromeDriver config
    # goog:chromeOptions:
    #   args: 
    #      - "--headless"
    #      - "--disable-gpu"
    #      - "--mute-audio"

  # DelegatorRemoteDriverProtocol
  selenium.delegated.protocol: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.protocol.httpclient.HttpProtocol"

  # no url or parsefilters by default
  parsefilters.config.file: "parsefilters.json"
  urlfilters.config.file: "urlfilters.json"

  # JSoupParserBolt
  jsoup.treat.non.html.as.error: false
  parser.emitOutlinks: true
  parser.emitOutlinks.max.per.page: -1
  track.anchors: true
  detect.mimetype: true
  detect.charset.maxlength: 10000

  # filters URLs in sitemaps based on their modified Date (if any)
  sitemap.filter.hours.since.modified: -1

  # staggered scheduling of sitemaps
  sitemap.schedule.delay: -1

  # whether to add any sitemaps found in the robots.txt to the status stream
  # used by fetcher bolts
  sitemap.discovery: false

  # Default implementation of Scheduler
  scheduler.class: "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.persistence.DefaultScheduler"

  # revisit a page daily (value in minutes)
  # set it to -1 to never refetch a page
  fetchInterval.default: 1440

  # revisit a page with a fetch error after 2 hours (value in minutes)
  # set it to -1 to never refetch a page
  fetchInterval.fetch.error: 120

  # never revisit a page with an error (or set a value in minutes)
  fetchInterval.error: -1

  # custom fetch interval to be used when a document has the key/value in its metadata
  # and has been fetched succesfully (value in minutes)
  # fetchInterval.FETCH_ERROR.isFeed=true
  # fetchInterval.isFeed=true: 10

  # max number of successive fetch errors before changing status to ERROR
  max.fetch.errors: 3

  # Guava cache use by AbstractStatusUpdaterBolt for DISCOVERED URLs
  status.updater.use.cache: true
  status.updater.cache.spec: "maximumSize=10000,expireAfterAccess=1h"

  # Can also take "MINUTE" or "HOUR"
  status.updater.unit.round.date: "SECOND"

  # configuration for the classes extending AbstractIndexerBolt
  # indexer.md.filter: "someKey=aValue"
  indexer.url.fieldname: "url"
  indexer.text.fieldname: "content"
  indexer.text.maxlength: -1
  indexer.canonical.name: "canonical"
  indexer.md.mapping:
  - parse.title=title
  - parse.keywords=keywords
  - parse.description=description
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http.agent.name: "Anonymous Coward"
...

It's good practice to use a real user agent and a genuine email address so that web masters can contact you

Comment: anything relevant to that site in your logs?

Comment: I have set a proper user agent but still the same result. this is a sample log while fetching the data: `Parsed https://cactussara.ir/?add-to-cart=2358 in 111 msec
55802 [Thread-29-spout-executor[9 9]] INFO  c.d.s.s.p.SolrSpout - SOLR returned 5 results from 1 buckets in 8 msec including 5 already being processed
`

Comment: I have to add this point that my co-workers have tried to crawl this website using Apache Nutch, but they got none too.

Comment: OK, so you use SOLR. what do you get when querying the SOLR index for that particular URL?  does the index contain documents at all or is it that they are empty?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SOLR. In status, I see that URLs are getting parsed and fetched but in doc there is absolutely nothing. this is a query in doc: `{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pages contain

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow"/>
```

which are found by the parser and causes the indexer bolt to skip the page.

This should be confirmed in the metrics where *Filtered* should be the same number as the pages fetched.

*http.skip.robots* does not apply to the directives set in the page itself.

Comment: I've noticed that too. So you mean this website is not crawlable at all? Is there any configuration that can handle this problem?!

Comment: I have also set `robots.noFollow.strict` to `false` but still the same.

Comment: not out of the box, please open an issue on github if you want that feature. In the meantime you could have your own copy of the JSOUP parser bolt and modify it.